# private specifier in php

Tags: php, class

According to my knowledge we cant use private property in inherited class . then what is this.it still working

```
<?php

class oops1 
{
    private $text;

    function __construct($txt) 
    {
        $this->text=$txt;
    }

    function disply()
    {
        echo 'text:'.$this->text;

    }
}

class abc extends oops1
{
    public $headertext;

    function __construct($ht,$txt) 
    {
        $this->headertext=$ht;
        $this->text=$txt;
    }

    function disp2()
    {
        echo "Header Text: $this->headertext";
        echo "<br>Text: $this->text";
    } 
}

$obj=new abc("g", "h"); 
$obj->disp2();
```

it still showing headertext and text which is defined in base class as private... whats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is creating a class property in this line:

```
$this->text=$txt;
```

If you take it away and initialize it in the base class like this:

```
private $text = "test";
```

And then you try to access it you won't be able to

Comment: When you're doing `$this->text=$txt;` in class abc you're actually creating a property named `$text` that belongs to class abc, thus you can access it directly in class abc since it belongs to that class. IF you want to assign `$this->text = $txt` to class oops1 you'd have to call `parent::__cosntruct()`. In all fairness it's a bit weird that you can create class properties on the fly, first time I've seen it.

Comment: but as i read by $this->r=text ,,,we access the present class property...then how it creating property.....how i cn solve it

Comment: @Davinderkumar I don't really understand what you mean?

Comment: i say...i read that by using $this we can only access the property of present class....then how it creating property

Comment: @Rizier123 He's confused as to why a property is being created "on the fly" when you assign variables to not yet declared properties. I can somewhat see why he'd be confused on the subject.

Comment: @Davinder You can create new properties on PHP objects at any time. `$this->foo = 'bar';` works anytime anywhere.

Comment: ok bro....so there is another method to access base class's property instead of creating property

Comment: @Davinderkumar If I understand you right: If the property in the base class exists the you can access it like this: `$this->foo` if you have it in your child class then you overwrite your base class and if it doesn't exists anywhere and you assign something the you create a property

Comment: i write it as...$this->text;....now it gives error which all i want :) thakew bro.....u help me out...thanku so much :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, if you attempt to set a class property that does not exist, then it will be created as a **`public`** property. You are correct in your assumption that a private property may not be accessed by child classes.

If the intention here is for your child class to be able to access the property of its parents without making the property accessible outside of the class structure, then use **`protected`**.

Comment: i just want to access base property which gives the error instead of creating property :(